# Client Only Tags Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js

Very simple question but I do not find any clear answer on the Internet, if I am using client-only tags on nuxt SSR for some part of my HTML, will it damage the SSR itself and make SEO not optimal?

Comment: `client-only` means that this what is inside will not be SSR'ed at all, only done on the client-side, as you'd find in a Vue app.

Comment: @kissu I have data put in client-only tag because an error pops up, will that have any impact on my SEO?

Comment: Depends on what you put inside of it but probably yes.

Comment: @kissu I solved the problem of client-only tag and replaced it with v-if and before mounted it will have loading animation, can google crawl it?

Comment: Pretty generic question. Simplest would be to check the source code. Otherwise yeah, Google is already able to parse async JS code.